# Getting error "Can not retrieve link from link field" while importing

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am getting error 'Cannot retrieve link from link field while content importing using content porter'. But I am not able to figure out where exactly the problem is existing. Help!!!!!

Comment: Hey Alok. If the answer below solved your problem, can you please accept that answer by clicking the large check mark to its left? That way others can benefit from knowing how you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Figured out the issue. There was a change in structure group metadata schema in which there was a drop down to select yes or no. When I changed this value in structure group and done save and close. then the issue resolved. For some of the pages this thing is working but still some are not getting imported.

Comment: Schema changes aren't immediately reflected in components and pages. Open, change (try adding a space after the title, for example), and save the pages that are giving you issues then redo the export and import at least for those.